# How is one supposed to recover from a failed migration in South?

Tags: django, database-migration, django-south

I'm using [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) (version 0.6, the one packaged in Ubuntu Lucid Lynx) to manage database migrations in Django, and currently using SQLite as a back end.  I came across a situation where I generated a migration to add a column with:

```
./manage.py startmigration myapp --auto added_new_column
```

... which generated a migration that looked sensible.  However, when I then applied the migration with:

```
./manage.py migrate myapp
```

I got an error because the column I was adding was non-NULL, but I hadn't specified a default value:

```
ValueError: You cannot add a null=False column without a default value.
```

What is one supposed to do if a migration fails in this way, and you want to go back and regenerate it?  (What I did in practice, namely to delete the migration and generate a new one, has created several further problems.)  Perhaps I've missed something obvious in the documentation about this...

Comment: you can use `migrate app --list` to see which migration you're using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, migration failed and didn't get written into db, so you can safely remove old one and create again. Also you can try using newer south version, i believe they added default check for NOT NULL fields on creating step.

Comment: Thanks - I thought that the `startmigration myapp --auto` had affected the db, but I guess that was actually done by the later steps that I tried.